# RAM info with dmidecode --type 17

Tags: linux, ram

On the motherboard ASUS V-PRO Z77 installed 2x2 (Kingston and Corsair) memory slots. All four slats of RAM do not cause any complaints. They work properly. But, below is the output of the result of running the dmidecode program and in the output I'm interested in the following lines:
Error Information Handle: 0x0060
Error Information Handle: 0x0063
What does it mean?
What are the reasons for these errors?
Unfortunately, I could not find information about this in Google.

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type 17
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0x000f04c0
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x005B, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: 0x0060
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 9333B00B
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 99U5584-007.A00LF 
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x005F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: 029E
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x0062, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: 0x0063
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 1D10C373
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 99U5584-018.A00LF 
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x0065, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005C
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: 029E
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz
```

**UPD**

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type 18
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0x000f04c0
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x005D, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0060, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0063, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x0066, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
```

Comment: FYI: this is a clone of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023105/ram-info-with-dmidecode-type-17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look at dmidecode sources available [online](https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode/blob/master/dmidecode.c):

```
    case 17: /* 7.18 Memory Device */
        printf("Memory Device\n");
        if (h->length < 0x15) break;
        if (!(opt.flags & FLAG_QUIET))
        {
            printf("\tArray Handle: 0x%04X\n",
                WORD(data + 0x04));
            printf("\tError Information Handle:");
            dmi_memory_array_error_handle(WORD(data + 0x06));
            printf("\n");
```

Ok, so `Error Information Handle:` comes from some data structure offset 0x06, probably some dmi data, cause the program is named dmidecode.
We search for offset 0x06 in dmi specification: [SMBIOS specification](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.7.1.pdf) section `7.18 Memory Device (Type 17)` in `Table 71 - Memory Device (Type 17) Structure` we find `Memory Error Information Handle` with description:

```
The handle, or instance number, associated with
any error that was previously detected for the
device. if the system does not provide the error
information structure, the field contains FFFEh;
otherwise, the field contains either FFFFh (if no
error was detected) or the handle of the errorinformation
structure. See 7.18.4 and 7.34.
```

In section `7.34 64-Bit Memory Error Information (Type 33)` you may find `Table 100 - 64-Bit Memory Error Information (Type 33) structure`.

So `Error Information Handle: <handle>` in `dmidecode --type 17` output means there is a value in `Memory Error Information Handle` of your dmi structure of your memory card. This means that your BIOS has detected an error associated with your memory card and the handles `0x0060` and `0x0063` may be used to retrieve a error information structures about the last detected error.
Anyway try `dmidecode --type 33` to further investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated my question. Please, look at the output of the result of the command `dmidecode --type 18` (I have 32-Bit Memory). It looks like there are no errors. What do you think about this?

Comment: SMBIOS is just a reference specification, it does not tell bios manufactures what to do with errors (i think), only (to some extent) how system may extract some information from bios. What happens with errors is specific to your hardware and manufacturer and bios version. You can see that `Error Type` in type 18 is `The type of error that is associated with the **current status** reported for the memory array or device.` Probably there was an error, but current status is OK. The only valid conclusion would be 'Your bios does not currently provide the specified memory error information'.